# Where can I find a list of all Domains available?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, domains, dragonlance

I am working on making a Mystic in a 3.5e campaign and at first level you get to select a domain.  Does anyone know where I can find a full list of every domain available to a Mystic?  We are using all material available in 3.5e.

I am interested in all domains from WOTC-licensed material for the Dragonlance campaign setting.

Comment: You want every domain in *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* inclusive issued by Wizards of the Coast (i.e. and Web material and magazines) plus domains in Wizards of the Coast-licensed material for the Dragonlance campaign setting? Is that right? (That may sound like a lot, but I don't think at this point in the game's history it's out of line to ask for this info directly rather than asking for an off-site resource that may yield icky link-only answers, but I'll try to keep an eye on this question to see if it needs revision to keep it as not a shopping question.)

Comment: That is correct, any and all domains available, so long as they are not homebrew.

Comment: It's the *plus domains in Wizards of the Coast-licensed material for the Dragonlance campaign setting* part that's kind of important. If that's true, does that also mean you want similarly licensed material (i.e. not published by Wizards of the Coast but bearing the Wizards of the Coast-approved seal) like domains from the Oriental Adventures and Kalamar product lines?

Comment: Just the WOTC-licensed material for the Dragonlance campaign setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best resources are [IMarvinTPA’s domain list](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/Index_LevDom.php) (and check out the rest of his site, too) and [Curmudgeon’s list](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219065916/http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/domains.html) (with [planar domains here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170321161338/http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/PlanarDomains.html)). I am reasonably confident that Curmudgeon’s list is the most thorough available in D&D 3.5e.

These skirt the line with respect to Fair Use, but have been around for a long time and become fairly well-known among D&D 3.5e optimizers, without any legal action taken against them by Wizards of the Coast (unlike other, more detailed—but usually less complete—listings).

Combining the two lists to get the actual domains, we have:

> - Abyss Domain (*Spell Compendium* 282) **planar**
> - Air Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 185)
> - Animal Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Arborea Domain (*Spell Compendium* 282-283) **planar**
> - Army Domain (*Dragon* #317 78)
> - Artifice Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 104)
> - Avarice Domain (*Dragon* #323 63)
> - Baator Domain (*Spell Compendium* 283) **planar**
> - Balance Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271)
> - Beguilement Domain (*Dragon* #312 50)
> - Bestial Domain (*Book of Vile Darkness* 80)
> - Blackwater Domain (*Stormwrack* 109)
> - Blightbringer Domain (*Unapproachable East* 34)
> - Cavern Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271)
> - Celerity Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271)
> - Celestia Domain (*Spell Compendium* 283) **planar**
> - Celestial Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 86)
> - Chaos Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Charity Domain (*Dragon* #355 25)
> - Charm Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271)
> - Chastity Domain (*Dragon* #355 25-26)
> - City Domain (*Races of Destiny* 162-163)
> - Cold Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271)
> - Commerce Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 105)
> - Community Domain (*Spell Compendium* 271-272)
> - Competition Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272)
> - Corruption Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 88)
> - Courage Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272)
> - Craft Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272)
> - Creation Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272)
> - Darkness Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272)
> - Death Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Deathbound Domain (*Spell Compendium* 272-273)
> - Deathless Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 105)
> - Decay Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 105)
> - Demonic Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 88-89)
> - Destiny Domain (*Races of Destiny* 163)
> - Destruction Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Diabolic Domain (*Fiendish Codex II* 100)
> - Domination Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - Dragon Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - Dragon Below Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 106)
> - Dream Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - DrgBlw
> - Drow Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - Dwarf Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - Earth Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Elf Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273)
> - Elysium Domain (*Spell Compendium* 283-284) **planar**
> - Emotion Domain (*Dragon* #340 54)
> - Endurance Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 86)
> - Entropy Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 89)
> - Envy Domain (*Spell Compendium* 273-274)
> - Evil Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 186)
> - Exorcism Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 106)
> - Family Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Fate Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Feast Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 106)
> - Fey Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 86)
> - Fire Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Force Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Forge Domain (*Dragonlance Campaign Setting* 102)
> - Fury Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 89)
> - Generosity Domain (*Dragon* #355 26-28)
> - Ghost Domain (*Ghostwalk* 46)
> - Glory Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Gluttony Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Gnome Domain (*Spell Compendium* 274)
> - Good Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Greed Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275)
> - Hades Domain (*Spell Compendium* 284) **planar**
> - Halfling Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275)
> - Hatred Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275)
> - Healing Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Herald Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 87)
> - Hope Domain (*Dragon* #340 46)
> - Humility Domain (*Dragon* #355 28)
> - Hunger Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275)
> - Hunt Domain (*Dragon* #342 89)
> - Illusion Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275)
> - Incarnum Domain (*Magic of Incarnum* 96)
> - Inquisition Domain (*Spell Compendium* 275-276)
> - Insight Domain (*Dragonlance Campaign Setting* 102-103)
> - Joy Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 87)
> - Knowledge Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Kobold Domain ([*Races of the Dragon* web enhancement, part 2](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060420a))
> - Law Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Liberation Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276)
> - Life Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 106)
> - Limbo Domain (*Spell Compendium* 284) **planar**
> - Luck Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 187)
> - Lust Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276)
> - Madness Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276)
> - Magic Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Mechanus Domain (*Spell Compendium* 284-285) **planar**
> - Meditation Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 107)
> - Mental
> - Mentalism Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276)
> - Metal Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276)
> - Mind Domain (*Spell Compendium* 276-277)
> - Moon Domain (*Spell Compendium* 277)
> - Mysticism Domain (*Spell Compendium* 277)
> - Necro
> - Necromancer Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 107)
> - Night Domain (*Dragon* #342 89)
> - Nobility Domain (*Spell Compendium* 277)
> - Ocean Domain (*Spell Compendium* 277)
> - Ooze Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 89-90)
> - Oracle Domain (*Spell Compendium* 277-278)
> - Orc Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278)
> - Pact Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278)
> - Pain Domain (*Book of Vile Darkness* 81)
> - Passion Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 107)
> - Patience Domain (*Dragon* #355 28-29)
> - Pestilence Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278)
> - Planning Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278)
> - Plant Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Pleasure Domain (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 87)
> - Portal (alt)
> - Portal Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278)
> - Pride Domain (*Spell Compendium* 278-279)
> - Protection Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Purification Domain (*Spell Compendium* 279)
> - Radiance Domain (*Dragon* #321 68)
> - Renewal Domain (*Spell Compendium* 279)
> - Repose Domain (*Player’s Guide to Faerûn* 90)
> - Retribution Domain (*Spell Compendium* 279)
> - Rune Domain (*Spell Compendium* 279)
> - Sand Domain (*Sandstorm* 107)
> - SaveLife
> - Scalykind Domain (*Spell Compendium* 279)
> - Seafolk Domain (*Stormwrack* 110)
> - Seduction Domain (*Dragon* #312 50)
> - Shadow Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 108)
> - Sin-A
> - Sin-E
> - Sin-G
> - Sin-L
> - Sin-P
> - Sin-S
> - Sin-W
> - Sky Domain (*Races of the Wild* 174)
> - Slime Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280)
> - Sloth Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280)
> - Spell Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280)
> - Spider Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280)
> - Spirit Domain (*Dragon* #312 36-37)
> - Spite Domain (*Heroes of Horror* 126)
> - Storm Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280)
> - Strength Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Suffering Domain (*Spell Compendium* 280-281)
> - Summer Domain (*Sandstorm* 107-108)
> - Summoner Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - Sun Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Temperance Domain (*Dragon* #355 29-30)
> - Temptation Domain (*Fiendish Codex I* 90)
> - Thirst Domain (*Sandstorm* 108)
> - Time Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - Trade Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - Transformation Domain (*Races of Eberron* 180-181)
> - Travel Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 188)
> - Treachery Domain (*Dragonlance Campaign Setting* 104)
> - Trickery Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 189)
> - Truth Domain (*Races of Eberron* 181)
> - Tyranny Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - Undead Domain (*Dragon* #312 37)
> - Undeath Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - VDarkness
> - War Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 189)
> - Warforged Domain (*Faiths of Eberron* 150)
> - Water Domain (*Player’s Handbook* 189)
> - Watery Death
> - Wealth Domain (*Spell Compendium* 281)
> - Weather Domain (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 108)
> - Windstorm Domain (*Spell Compendium* 282)
> - Winter Domain (*Frostburn* 85)
> - Wrath Domain (*Spell Compendium* 282)
> - Zeal Domain (*Dragon* #355 30)

The entries without a book noted are the ones from IMarvinTPA but not in Curmudgeon’s list, since the book wasn’t listed in the main listing. Most of them appear to just be abbreviations, but I leave investigation there up to the reader.

Note that the **planar** domains take up both domain slots for a cleric. A mystic may or may not be able to actually take them; ask your DM.

Comment: I think that the DrgBlw and Necro domains are probably just the Dragon Below and Necromancy domains. I suspect that the Sin domains are probably related to the Seven Deadly Sins, but I’m not sure where they’re from off of the top of my head.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, I assume that too (A, E, G, L, P, S, W probably correspond to Avarice, Envy, Gluttony, Lust, Pride, Sloth, and Wrath, and VDarkness is almost-certainly the Vile Darkness domain), but since anyone interested in confirming those details can start clicking through IMarvinTPA’s site to find more details, I wasn’t interested in digging for them at this point.