# What are domains in dragonlance?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, dragonlance

I’m starting to look at other settings than Forgotten Realms and am interested to know how domains function in the Dragonlance fiction. I saw [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152494/53875)  and it mentions Dragonlance domains and its confusing me.

Is it the same as planes? Do you have to use portals to travel domains?

Comment: What do you already know/what have you read about the role of domains in Dragonlance? It might help people answer the question if they know what information you already have about them. (For instance, you seem to be talking about places, not cleric domains.)

Comment: I have read just about everything in DL and have run the classic DL-series modules and am not quite sure what you're talking about. Can you give us any touchstones? Where'd you run across the term?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Ravenloft?

Comment: I saw this question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152494/53875 and it mentions dragonlance domains and its confusing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The question you mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152494/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-domains-available) is just talking about cleric domains. Like other rulebooks, campaign setting books often introduce new domains that a cleric (or other class that uses them) can choose, though they're generally tied loosely enough to the setting's fluff that a more permissive DM would probably allow them to be used outside of that setting.

Based on a quick search of the list in the answer to that question, the Dragonlance Campaign Setting introduced the Forge, Insight, and Treachery domains, and if you look through the list you can see others that came from Eberron and Faerûn.